# Calling a static method of class type C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a newbie to `asp.net` and `c#`..I've been asked to analyse the code of a portal. Please look at the following code and suggest me a way to call the ***FromDatabase*** method. I've gone through all the files in the solution but there is no call statement to it.

Here Account and Utility are classes.

```
public static Account FromDatabase(DbDataRecord dr)
{
    return new Account(
        Utility.StringFromNull(dr.GetValue(0)),
        Utility.StringFromNull(dr.GetValue(1)),
        Utility.IntFromNull(dr.GetValue(2)),
        Utility.StringFromNull(dr.GetValue(3)),
        Utility.StringFromNull(dr.GetValue(4)),
        Utility.StringFromNull(dr.GetValue(5)),
        Utility.DateTimeFromNull(dr.GetValue(6))
    );
}
```

In what other way can I return the values instead of return **new Account()**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use it with: Account sampleAcc = FromDatabase(dr); since FromDatabase returns a new Account object

Comment: CTRL + K, CTRL + R

To see the References to that Method, vs2010pro

Comment: If you've gone through all the files in the solution and it's not being called, then I would suggest finding the way the rest of the codebase gets an account object and using that instead, as this method has quite likely not been maintained.

Comment: Hi all.. Thanks fo the reply!! It's visual studio 2005 and am not able to debug using breakpoints because there are error already existing in the code. In that case what do I do? I am not able to get the flow of the code..

Answer (score 2):

You can call a `static` method by using the `class` name that the `static` method belongs to...

**Example:**

```
public class MyClass {
   public static object MyMethod() {}
}
```

**To call it:**

```
MyClass.MyMethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

To use a static method you just use the class, and not an instance of it. I.E.: say your method is in class MyClass, then you just do

```
MyClass.FromDataBase(yourDataRow);
```

Comment: If the classes are within a namespace, you may need to specify it too. eg. MyNamespace.MyClass.FromDataBase(yourDataRow); or alternatively use a using directive to shortcut the namespace into the file you are making the call.

Comment: And also, is the classes are in different assemblies, you'll need to reference them.

Answer (score 1):

```
Account myAccount = Account.FromDatabase(dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

call it this way:

```
NameOfStaticClass.FromDatabase(dbRec)
```

and NameOfStaticClass is the name of class in witch FromDatabase method is declared

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `Account.FromDatabase` method by using the typeName of the class it lives in (I assumy it is a method on the `Account` class itself. However it will always result a `Account` object.

You can create another method that will parse the `DbDataRecord` object and return it in any collection object, for example an array.